# TS2331 'this' cannot be referenced in a module or namespace body

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, this

I am trying to create an interface and while implementing it getting an error.
**error: TS2331 'this' cannot be referenced in a module or namespace body.**

```
module myInterface {
    interface IPerson {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        greet: () => void;
        myAge: () => void;
    }

    var person: IPerson = {
        name: "Gautam",
        age: 1,
        greet: () => {
            console.log("Hey, " + this.name);
        },
        myAge: () => { console.log(this.age); }
    }

    var greetMe = person.greet();
    var agee = person.myAge();
}
```

Comment: Your `greet` and `myAge` functions are arrow functions so `this` won't be the person object.

Answer (score 2):

From your code :

```
{
        name: "Gautam",
        age: 1,
        greet: () => {
            console.log("Hey, " + this.name);
        },

}
```

`this.name` Does *not* refer to `name: "Gautam"` due to how arrow functions work with `this`. This is just another case of TypeScript [preventing bad JavaScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/recap.html).

## More

- Read up on arrow https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Instead of pulling in something as controversial as TypeScript you could just, you know, avoid using `this` in javascript ;)